# What's the purpose of an asp:hyperlink, and how many strings is too many in a resource file?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, localization, globalization

I developed a (small) company website in Visual Studio, and I'm addicted to learning more.  I really just have two simple questions that I can't google.

**1 - Asp:hyperlinks:**

What is the purpose of an asp.hyperlink?  I know I can't use these in my resource files -- I have to convert 'em all back to html links.  At first, asp:hyperlinks looked sophisticated, so I made all my links asp:hyperlinks.  Now I'm reverting back.  What's the purpose of an asp:hyperlink, if any?

**2 - Resource Files and strings:**

In localizing my website, I have found that I'm putting the **.master resource files** in the directory's **App_LocalResources** folder VS created, because you can't change the top line stuff in a .master file and put a culture/uiculture in there.  But all of my **regular .aspx pages** are going into the **root App_GlobalResources** folder into 1 of 4 language resource files (de, es-mx, fr, en).  I'm making 2 or 3 strings per .aspx page.  So when you have 47 pages in your website, that's about 100 strings on a resource page.

I just learned about all of the resources stuff from this forum and MSDN tutorials, so I have to ask, 'cause it's a lot of work.  Is this okay?  Is it normal?  Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: One question per question, please. Take the time to read the FAQ. This is not a forum.

Comment: Thanks for that, John.  I was worried that asking 2 questions in one post wouldn't be appropriate, and I know now it's not.  I won't do that in the future, and I'll edit my question pronto.

Comment: As per John's comment, please can you ask question #2 in a new post. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, I won't make the same mistake in the future again.  I'll make sure separate questions are on separate posts.  Thanks Kev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used resources, so can't comment on that.

Differences between asp:hyperlink and a tag that I know of:

1. asp:hyperlink is converted to an A tag by the ASP.NET engine when output to the browser.
2. It is possible asp:hyperlink could make browser specific adjustments, to overcome browser bugs/etc.. which is kind of the point of ASP.NET, or at least one of them.  If not already in it, they could be added later, and by using those objects you'll get that when/if added.
3. Both can be used in code behind (you can set runat="server" for an A tag), but the asp:hyperlink has better compile-time checking in most cases -- strong type-casting for more items vs generic objects.
4. asp:hyperlinks are easier to get HTML bloat, but only if used with a poor design.  For example, it is easy to set font styles and colors on them.. but I wouldn't, since that generates in-line styles that are usually pretty bloated compared to what you would do by hand or in a CSS file.
5. asp:hyperlinks support the "~/Folder/File.ext" syntax for the TargetUrl (href), which is nice in some projects if you use a lot of different URLs and sub-folders and want the server to handle mapping in a "smart" way.

Comment: I did not know you could set <a href ..... runat="server"> inside the tag.  I'm not sure what the runat="server" does, but I've considered trying to put it in there.  I think, by your posting, that asp:hyperlinks have a lot of current and future advantages, but they're not compatible with resource files, which negates my purpose.  Thank you for taking the time to respond!

Comment: You're welcome, and runat="server" just means you want to use the element in server-side code (VB or C#).  It makes it so the ID of the control becomes the name you can use in your code.  By default ASP.NET controls has that set for you, but you can set it on just about anything and reference them in your code as generic HTML controls (or typecast them as the actual HTML type for easier access to certain properties).  Do be aware that setting runat server changes the ID on the client-side, so if you want to work with it client-side (JavaScript) you need to use the special "ClientID" property.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of  is to display a link to another webpage.

With the resource files, since you're not a programmer and just developing a small program, use something you're comfortable with. Resource files are easy to use for beginners when you want to localize your web content -- and yes, it's normal to be adding many strings if you need them.

Comment: Thank you Ann!  I appreciate the response.  I really didn't know if what I was doing was "normal" or not, or if I was on the right path, but you taking the time to respond made me realize that I'm doing the right thing and I'm on the right track.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For #1

Using a hyperlink control over just a piece of text will allow you to access the control at runtime and manipulate its contents if you want to change the link dynamically, if you have static links that will never change then its simpler to just use plain text ie. `<a href=''>`

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your response.  I think with the resource files I'm using, it'd be more advantageous to use regular html hyperlinks on most occasions.  But thank you for describing what the asp:hyperlinks is for.  I appreciate your time!